# Is incremental area analysis possible in the adehabitatHR package?

Tags: r, range, analysis

I have home range data sets for 6 animals using UTM coordinates.  I have successfully read them into R and calculated each home range using the Minimum Convex Polygon(MCP) method.  I would like to know if it is possible to do an "incremental area analysis" on these data.  What I am looking for is a graph for each home range data set that has the number of data points on the X axis, and the MCP area of the points on the Y axis.  The idea is to look for an asymptote.  If an asymptote is found, then the area is not increasing with additional data.  This would allow me to conclude that the home range of the animal has been fully revealed.

Essentially, I need to know the area gained for each sequential data point.  Does adehabitatHR or its brother packages have this capability?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a script for IAA at the Faunalia webpage, I used it and it worked perfectly for MCP:

https://trac.faunalia.it/animove/wiki/AnimoveHowto

Comment: This link no longer works. Can someone please help me with this question as well?